# Set fetchSize for owned relationship in JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Is there a way to control the fetch size used for owned relationship ?

Example :

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Employee {

  /** The contact info sets. */
  @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
  @Element(dependent = "true")
  private Collection<ContactInfo> contactInfoSets;

  /** The key. */
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  public Collection<ContactInfo> getContactInfo() {
    return contactInfoSets;
  }

}

@PersistenceCapable
public class ContactInfo {

  /** The key. */
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

}
```

In the example above, if I do :

```
Employee e = pm.getObjectById(Employee.class, "1");
e.getContactInfoSets();
```

It will fetch every owned contact in group of 20. How to tell jdo to fetch all contacts in a single query ?

PS : I tried to set `pm.getFetchPlan().setFetchSize(FetchPlan.FETCH_SIZE_GREEDY);` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FetchPlan.setFetchSize is obviously for use by queries and nothing else (as per the spec). 
Use of v2 of the GAE JDO plugin ought to load all relation objects without any additional call to the DB (since the ids of the related objects are stored in the owning object). The log tells you what datastore calls are made